# Ide for multiple web contexts

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide, intellij-idea

I'm working on an old project where the developers did not use Ides like eclipse,netbeans etc I tried to create a dynamic web project, but eclipse allows for only one web context. The project has around 23 different webcontexts, is it possible to do this in eclipse without creating 23 different web projects. Are there any other Ide's like netbeans,Intellij which would allow me to do this?

Comment: Explain what you mean by webcontext. Do you mean the prefix to your web root?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, I mean a webapplication, which can be exported to a war file (here there are 23 wars)

Comment: I think you will need to have 23 projects, in Eclipse at least. One project per application.

Comment: On another note : Oo' good luck.

Comment: If you have time and like doing things well, you could mavenize your project, and create 23 webapp modules, but it can be rather long to configure. In IntelliJ, you could create a project and import your 23 projects as modules, which may be automatically recognized as web projects. It will then create 23 different web artifacts (war files), which can be deployed at the same time in a tomcat server, for example.